# Aligning chemical + and arrow with vline of tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, chemistry, cell

I would like to reproduce this figure:
[image: tabular with even length columns aligned on top row's + and rightarrow symbols]
So far, I have managed to come up with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\def\gaz{_{\rm(g)}}
\def\sol{_{\rm(s)}}
\def\liq{_{\rm(l)}}
\def\aqu{_{\rm(aq)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c||Y|Y|Y|Y|}\hline
        Équation &
        \multicolumn{4}{c|}{$\ce{CH4\gaz{} + 2O2\gaz{} ->
                           CO2\gaz{} + 2H2O\gaz{}}$}
                           \\\hline
        État initial & $n_{\ce{CH4}}^i$ & $n_{\ce{CH4}}^i$ &
                     $n_{\ce{CH4}}^i$ & $n_{\ce{CH4}}^i$
                     \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

which outputs the following:
[image: tabularx with even length columns unaligned with top row's + and rightarrow symboles]

How do I make it so that the `+` and `rightarrow` align with the `vlines` of the `tabular`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution, using a new columntype `d` for centering the math symbols, and using a simple `\vline` when needed.

The best option for centering the cell content is still the one suggested by Celdor. As you can see (commented lines), I tried lots of these.

[image: table as needed]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5cm, vmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{d}{@{}c@{}}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\def\gaz{_{\rm(g)}}
\def\sol{_{\rm(s)}}
\def\liq{_{\rm(l)}}
\def\aqu{_{\rm(aq)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    % \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
    % \setlength\extrarowheight{-3pt}
    % \def\mystrut{\rule[-1em]{0ex}{2.5em}}
    % \setlength\minrowclearance{10pt}
    % \setcellgapes{5em}\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{2cm}||YdYdYdY|}
        \hline
        $\xmathstrut{.35}$
        Équation         &
        $\ce{CH4\gaz{}}$ & $+$           &
        $\ce{2O2\gaz{}}$ & $\rightarrow$ &
        $\ce{CO2\gaz{}}$ & $+$           &
        $\ce{2H2O\gaz{}}$                  \\
        \hline
        $\xmathstrut{.35}$
        État initial     &
        $n_{\ce{CH4}}^i$ & \vline        &
        $n_{\ce{CH4}}^i$ & \vline        &
        $n_{\ce{CH4}}^i$ & \vline        &
        $n_{\ce{CH4}}^i$                   \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish the effect if you place two separate tables on top of each other: one where column separators are substituted by symbols (`@{<symbol>}`) and the other having a regular vertical bars  (see Table 1 in [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array)); BTW `array` is loaded by `tabularx`.

Since `X`-type set the same width given an equal number of columns, you just need to make sure the first column also has the same fixed width, hence I have used `p{<len>}`

Lastly, because in such situations, latex adds extra `\lineskip`, `\vspace{-\lineskip}` compensates for it

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash $}X<{$}}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\def\gaz{_{\rm(g)}}
\def\sol{_{\rm(s)}}
\def\liq{_{\rm(l)}}
\def\aqu{_{\rm(aq)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbh]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{2cm}|| Y @{$+$} Y @{$\rightarrow$} Y @{$+$} Y |}
    \hline
    Équation     & \xmathstrut{0.35}\ce{CH4\gaz{}} & \ce{2O2\gaz{}} & \ce{CO2\gaz{}} & \ce{2H2O\gaz{}}
  \end{tabularx}
  \par\vspace{-\lineskip}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{2cm}|| *4{Y|}}
    \hline
    État initial & \xmathstrut{0.35}n_{\ce{CH4}}^i & n_{\ce{CH4}}^i & n_{\ce{CH4}}^i & n_{\ce{CH4}}^i \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```